# Integral of Airy function containing a second order polynom

Tags: integration

I wonder if there is an analytic expression for

$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{Ai}(a x^2 + b x + c) dx$

As a Bonus:

$  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{- d x^2} \mathrm{Ai}(a x^2 + b x + c) dx$

where $a,b,c$ are Real and $d < 0$.

Comment: no closed-form answer unless $a=0$, I'm afraid...

Comment: Your best bet would be to represent $\mathrm{Ai}(\cdot)$ in terms of the modified Bessel function, $\mathrm{K}_{1/3}(\cdot)$, and see if your integrals can be reduced to one of those in Gradshteyn-Ryzhik (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradshteyn_and_Ryzhik). That book has pages of various integrals involving products of Bessel functions with rational functions and exponentials...